# Correlation Matrix Not Squared

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I'm working with a Pandas DataFrame and I want to compute the correlation between two columns and all the others, does anyone know how can I do it? I think it should be pretty easy but I'm stuck up.

For instance, I got this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 5, 7, 8],  
                    "B":[5, 8, 4, 3], 
                    "C":[10, 4, 9, 3],
                    "D":[10, 4, 9, 3],
                    "E":[10, 4, 9, 3],
                    "F":[10, 4, 9, 3]})
```

And I want to get the Correlation Matrix, or the correlation factors, between E, F and all the other columns. How can I do it? I've tried with pandas.corrwith() but the DataFrames must have the same shape, which doesn't happen in this case.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the question. For the example data, are you able to calculate the desired result by hand? Could you show exactly what result you expect, and trace through the logic?

Comment: Hi @KarlKnechtel, I would like to compute exactly the same as .corr() but without the computational effort of computing the correlation between A,B,C and D with themselves. I just want to know the correlation between E,F and A,B,C,D.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `corr()`:

```
corrMatrix = df1.corr()

print(corrMatrix)
          A         B         C         D         E         F
A  1.000000 -0.398756 -0.597881 -0.597881 -0.597881 -0.597881
B -0.398756  1.000000 -0.131812 -0.131812 -0.131812 -0.131812
C -0.597881 -0.131812  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
D -0.597881 -0.131812  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
E -0.597881 -0.131812  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
F -0.597881 -0.131812  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000

# Or with corrwith():

df1.corrwith(df1['E'])

A   -0.597881
B   -0.131812
C    1.000000
D    1.000000
E    1.000000
F    1.000000
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 5, 7, 8],  
                    "B":[5, 8, 4, 3], 
                    "C":[10, 4, 9, 3],
                    "D":[10, 4, 9, 3],
                    "E":[10, 4, 9, 3],
                    "F":[10, 4, 9, 3]}) 

df1.corrwith(df1['E'])
Out[99]: 
A   -0.597881
B   -0.131812
C    1.000000
D    1.000000
E    1.000000
F    1.000000
dtype: float64
```